# My image is flowing out from my div column. How I can fix it and made the image full-size into div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have one container with full width (container-fluid) and card-desk inside it I have one vertical column and 2 rows, one with 3 columns and another one with 2 columns. The problem is that my image moved out ( flows out) from my div col, I used overflow-hidden, but it doesn't help. I used Cards, but also nothing at all. In CSS I add `img{ width:100%; height:auto}` no result again.It must be responsive so I can't use custom height and width.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden">
 <div class="card-deck">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-12">
 <img src="https://www.artgalleryofhamilton.com/wp- 
 content/uploads/2018/04/abstract-painting.jpg"class="card-img img- 
 fluid"/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xl-9  col-md-9 col-12">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12">
 <img src="https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp- 
 content/uploads/2017/09/shutterstock_664474234-825x465.jpg"class="card- 
 img img-fluid"/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12">
 <img src="https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp- 
 content/uploads/2017/09/shutterstock_664474234-825x465.jpg"class="card- 
 img img-fluid"/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12">
 <img src="https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp- 
 content/uploads/2017/09/shutterstock_664474234-825x465.jpg"class="card- 
 img img-fluid"/>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12">
 <img src="https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp- 
 content/uploads/2017/09/shutterstock_664474234-825x465.jpg"class="card- 
 img img-fluid"/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-8 col-12">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524721696987-b9527df9e512? 
 ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"class="card-img img- 
 fluid"/>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

What I did:
[image]
What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this  by setting the images as `background-image`

```css
.img-6 {
  background: url(https://www.artgalleryofhamilton.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/abstract-painting.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px
}

.img-1 {
  background: url(https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/shutterstock_664474234-825x465.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150px
}

.img-2 {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524721696987-b9527df9e512?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-6 ">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 img-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 img-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 img-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 img-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 img-2">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```